# window.CSSLint not defined, CodeMirror CSS linting cannot run. Angular 15

Tags: angular, codemirror, angular15, csslint

How to define CSSLint in Angular 15? for CodeMirror 5

[image]

Css lint is not working for my codemirror 5 editor

```
  <ngx-codemirror [(ngModel)]="cmEditor[0]" [options]="cmEditorOption"
       (cursorActivity)="getIndexOfLineColumn($event, 0);" #editor>
  </ngx-codemirror>

  cmEditorOption = {
    mode: 'text/css',
    theme: 'default',
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    foldGutter: true,
    gutters: ['CodeMirror-linenumbers', 'CodeMirror-foldgutter', 'CodeMirror-lint-markers'],
    autoCloseBrackets: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    matchClosing: true,
    alignCDATA: true,
    lint: true,
    lintGutter: true
  }
```